# Vertical space between stanzas

Tags: sheet-music, lilypond

I have some songs with several stanzas. I would like to control the vertical space between the first and second stanza and the second and third stanza, .... individually.

How is that possible by using LilyPond?

Comment: check \vspace in the stanza documentation, is that what you want?

Comment: Yes, you are right! The vertical space can be adjusted similar to the TeX "vspace", provided "\markup" is used. But I didn't get it, how to change the vertical space if "\Lyrics" is used.

Answer (score 4):

This will be your guide: [4.4.1 Flexible vertical spacing within systems > Within-system spacing properties](http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.18/Documentation/notation/flexible-vertical-spacing-within-systems#within_002dsystem-spacing-properties).

Rather than `\vspace` which is used in `\markup`, what you need is to find out the properties that affect the *context* `Lyrics`. If you want to modify the distances individually between stanzas, you need to individually declare those changes per `Lyrics` context (or whatever context you want to change). Here's a short example:

```
\version "2.18.2"
melody = \relative c' {
  \key f \major
  \time 3/4
  \repeat unfold 3 {
    f4 a g bes a c bes g
  }
}
words = \lyricmode {
  \repeat unfold 24 { la }
}
\score { 
  <<
    \new Voice = "align" \melody
    \new Lyrics \with {
      \override VerticalAxisGroup.nonstaff-relatedstaff-spacing = #'((padding . 2)) % between above Voice and this Lyrics
      \override VerticalAxisGroup.nonstaff-nonstaff-spacing = #'((padding . 2)) % between this Lyrics and below Lyrics
    } \lyricsto "align" \words
    \new Lyrics \with {
      \override VerticalAxisGroup.nonstaff-nonstaff-spacing = #'((padding . 4)) % between this Lyrics and below Lyrics
    } \lyricsto "align" \words
    \new Lyrics \with {
      \override VerticalAxisGroup.nonstaff-nonstaff-spacing = #'((padding . 6)) % between this Lyrics and below Lyrics
    } \lyricsto "align" \words
    \new Lyrics \with {
      \override VerticalAxisGroup.nonstaff-nonstaff-spacing = #'((padding . 8)) % between this Lyrics and below Lyrics
    } \lyricsto "align" \words
    \new Lyrics \with {
      \override VerticalAxisGroup.nonstaff-unrelatedstaff-spacing = #'((padding . 10)) % between this Lyrics and below Voice
    } \lyricsto "align" \words
    \new Voice \melody
  >>
}
```

[image: Using VerticalAxisGroup to show differing distances between stanzas]

You can read the documentation to glean what `nonstaff`, `relatedstaff`, and `unrelatedstaff` are, but I think they're pretty logical once you start fiddling with these. The comments next to the lines in the code I wrote above should give you a bit of insight.